How to parallelize a simple loop over a matrix?
I have a large matrix and I want to output all the indices where the elements in the matrix are less than 0. I have this MWE in numba:

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random(size = (1000, 1000)) - 0.1
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def numba_only(arr):
    rows = np.empty(arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1])
    cols = np.empty(arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1])
    idx = 0
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            if arr[i, j] < 0:
                rows[idx] = i
                cols[idx] = j
                idx += 1
    return rows[:idx], cols[:idx]

Timing, I get:
%timeit numba_only(A)
2.29 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

This is a faster than np.where(A<0) (without numba) which gives:
%timeit numpy_only(A)
3.56 ms ± 59.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

But it is a little slower than np.where wrapped by @nb.njit:
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def numba_where(arr):
    return np.where(arr<0)

which gives:
%timeit numba_where(A)
1.76 ms ± 84.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Can the numba code be sped up by parallelization somehow?  I realise it might be memory bound but I think that modern hardware should allow some level of parallel access to memory.
I am not sure how to use nb.prange to achieve this due to the index idx in the loop.

The provided algorithm is inherently sequential due to the long dependency chain of instruction which is also data dependent. However, this is possible to do an equivalent operation in parallel using a scan.
Implementing such a parallel algorithm based on a scan is much more complex (especially an efficient cache-friendly scan). A relatively simple implementation is to iterate twice on the dataset so to compute local sums, then compute cumulative sums and finally do the actual work.
@nb.njit(cache=True, parallel=True)
def numba_parallel_where(arr):
    flattenArr = arr.reshape(-1)
    arrSize = flattenArr.size
    chunkSize = 2048
    chunkCount = (arrSize + chunkSize - 1) // chunkSize
    counts = np.empty(chunkCount, dtype=np.int32)
    for chunkId in nb.prange(chunkCount):
        start = chunkId * chunkSize
        end = min(start + chunkSize, arrSize)
        count = 0
        for i in range(start, end):
            count += flattenArr[i] < 0
        counts[chunkId] = count
    offsets = np.empty(chunkCount + 1, dtype=np.int64)
    offsets[0] = 0
    for chunkId in range(chunkCount):
        offsets[chunkId + 1] = offsets[chunkId] + counts[chunkId]
    outSize = offsets[-1]
    rows = np.empty(outSize, dtype=np.int32)
    cols = np.empty(outSize, dtype=np.int32)
    n = np.int32(arr.shape[1])
    for chunkId in nb.prange(chunkCount):
        start = chunkId * chunkSize
        end = min(start + chunkSize, arrSize)
        idx = offsets[chunkId]
        for i in range(start, end):
            if flattenArr[i] < 0:
                rows[idx] = i // n
                cols[idx] = i % n
                idx += 1
    return rows, cols


Performance Results
Here are performance results on my 6-core i5-9600KF CPU with a 40 GiB/s RAM (optimal bandwidth for reads) on Windows:
Sequential:                         1.68 ms
Parallel (no pre-allocations):      0.85 ms
Parallel (with pre-allocations):    0.55 ms   <-----
Theoretical optimal:                0.20 ms

The parallel implementation is about twice faster. It succeed to reach a memory throughput of ~19 GiB/s on my machine which is sub-optimal, but not so bad. While this seems disappointing on a 6-core CPU, the parallel implementation is not very optimized and there are several points to consider:

allocating the output is really slow (is seems to take 0.2-0.3 ms)
the input array is read twice putting a lot of pressure on memory
modulo/division used to compute the indices are a bit expensive

Pre-allocating the output (filled manually with zeros to avoid possible page-faults) and passing it to the function helps to significantly reduce the execution time. This optimized version is 3 times faster than the initial (sequential) one. It reaches ~28 GiB/s which is relatively good.

Notes about Performance
Other possible optimizations include:

using clusters of chunks so to avoid iterating twice on the whole dataset (this is hard in Numba to write a fast implementation since parallelism is very limited compared to native languages);
iterate over lines of the matrix to avoid modulos/divisions assuming the number of lines is neither too big nor to small for sake of performance.

AFAIK, there is an opened bug for the slow Numba allocations since few years but it has obviously not been solved yet. On top of that, relatively large allocations can be quite expensive on Windows too. A natively-compiled code (written in C/C++/Fortran/Rust) on Linux should not exhibit such an issue.
Note that such optimizations will make the implementation even more complex than the above one.

Is the dependency chain just from idx? That is just from where to put the output?

Roughly, yes. the value of idx is dependent of whether the previous conditions have been taken or not. Modern CPUs are very "smart" since they can assume that the condition is often not taken here (thanks to branch prediction) based on an internal feedback loop. Based on this, they can test many conditions arr[i, j] < 0 very quickly. Some of them can even be tested in parallel on recent CPUs. However, when one condition turns out to be miss-predicted, this is a disaster for performance. Indeed, the CPU needs to revert the operations and re-execute the code due to the miss-prediction.

This big miss-prediction latency (e.g. >10 cycles) happens on the critical path : the dependency chain of idx increase instructions. The CPU cannot store anything dependent on idx as long as it as not been fixed. When arr[i, j] < 0 is often false (like here), CPUs can almost ignore the dependency chain and execute instructions in parallel and pipeline them. When it is often true, the dependency chain is the idx increase. When the outcome is not predictable, the dependency chain is the idx conditional increase + the latency of the conditional branch.

Because of that, the performance of the sequential/parallel versions is dependent of the probability of arr[i, j] < 0 and even its predictability. The parallel version should scale better when arr[i, j] < 0 is not predictable (because there is more CPU-bound work which is embarrassingly parallel).

Put it shortly: the dependency chain contains idx increase instruction, but we can also consider the conditional branches as a part of the dependency chain regarding the practical use-case.

Would an alternative be to make an empty array of length arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1], write to that at index i * arr.shape[0] + j if arr[i, j] < 0, thereby removing the dependency completely? There would then need to be another pass to move all the written values to the beginning of the array so it might not be a speedup.

You can optimize the sequential code further yes, typically using conditional mov to reduce the length of the critical path (in term of clocks). But in the end, there will still be a long dependency chain. You can reduce it with small chunks like in the parallel version but this is quite complicated to do efficiently. SIMD instructions can help in this case too. That being said, I do not think your solution works. The problem is then to gather the result so items to be contiguously stored. In your solution items are stored in a sparse way. This gathering is the expensive part.

The part before the gathering should be in parallelizable as there is no dependency I was hoping. But the gathering at the end is a bottleneck as you say.

The other pass would be a loop checking if arr[i] == 0 and then incrementing idx so to move the value to result[idx]. This is roughly what the initial algorithm does ;) .

The part before the gathering is not much the expensive part and modern CPU can execute the instruction arr[i, j] < 0 very quickly in parallel since there is no dependencies. Your solution will likely be slower because it requires more data to be written and then read again from the RAM. It may be slightly faster though if you can do that chunk-by chunk (in the L1 cache) and if you use SIMD instructions in the first part. Note that SIMD instructions sets like AVX-512 provide a way to vectorize the second part.

The later part is hard to parallelize using multiple threads and a solution is to use the method in this answer ;) .

This is a lot faster on my machine! %timeit numba_parallel_where(A)
657 µs ± 35.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
